# Conditionally sort a Vec in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Let's say I want to sort a Vec of **non-Clone** items - but only maybe (this is a boiled down example of an issue in my code).

My attempt would be something like:

```rust
fn maybe_sort<T>(x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: std::cmp::Ord,
{
    // First, I need a copy of the vector - but only the vector, not the items inside
    let mut copied = x.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    copied.sort();
    // In my actual code the line below depends on the sorted vec
    if rand::random() {
        return copied.into_iter().map(|x| *x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Alas the borrow checker isn't happy. I have a shared reference to each item in the Vec, and although I am not ever returning 2 references to the same item, Rust can't tell.

Is there a way to do this without `unsafe`? (and if not, what's the cleanest way to do it with `unsafe`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*only the vector, not the items inside*"? Additionally, sorting a vector does not require copying it. Anyway, you can do anything you want with the vector, since you are passing and returning it by value.

Comment: why not just sort `x`? [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6154f34b61f96b0ced791f49234a7df3)

Comment: I added a comment above the coin-flip line that hopefully makes it clearer - I need to first sort, then decide whether to return it or not.

Comment: @Acorn "only the vector, not the items inside" - I mean just that I cannot clone the items inside. The items are not cloneable.

Comment: @xixixao Any reason you can't `Clone`? (as in, is your type really that "big"?). It's possible to do what you want, and I'm writing an answer currently, but it requires double sorting the `Vec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `.enumerate()` the values to keep their original index. You can sort this based on its value `T` and decide whether to return the sorted version, or reverse the sort by sorting by original index.

```
fn maybe_sort<T: Ord>(x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut items: Vec<_> = x.into_iter().enumerate().collect();
    items.sort_by(|(_, a), (_, b)| a.cmp(b));
    
    if rand::random() {
        // return items in current order
    }
    else {
        // undo the sort
        items.sort_by_key(|(index, _)| *index);
    }
    
    items.into_iter().map(|(_, value)| value).collect()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful given it actually works. I feel like there should be a solution that doesn't involve another sort (and the code complexity involved, especially in my code which is more complicated than the example), but I'm gonna accept this for now.

Answer (score 1):

If `T` implements `Default`, you can do it with a single sort and without `unsafe` like this:

```
fn maybe_sort<T: Ord + Default> (mut x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut idx = (0..x.len()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    idx.sort_by_key (|&i| &x[i]);
    if rand::random() {
        return x;
    } else {
        let mut r = Vec::new();
        r.resize_with (x.len(), Default::default);
        for (i, v) in idx.into_iter().zip (x.drain(..)) {
            r[i] = v;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=baa9030ebd26278111cc480bab2c45a0)

If `T` does not implement `Default`, the same thing can be done with [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html):

```
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

fn maybe_sort<T: Ord> (mut x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut idx = (0..x.len()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    idx.sort_by_key (|&i| &x[i]);
    if rand::random() {
        return x;
    } else {
        let mut r = Vec::new();
        r.resize_with (x.len(), || unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() });
        for (i, v) in idx.into_iter().zip (x.drain(..)) {
            r[i] = MaybeUninit::new (v);
        }
        return unsafe { mem::transmute::<_, Vec<T>> (r) };
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=60062ab3970732321f91f7dc91297d46)

Finally, here's a safe solution which doesn't require `T` to implement `Default`, but allocates an extra buffer (there is theoretically a way to reorder the indices in place, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader ☺):

```
fn maybe_sort<T: Ord> (mut x: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut idx = (0..x.len()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    idx.sort_by_key (|&i| &x[i]);
    if rand::random() {
        let mut rev = vec![0; x.len()];
        for (i, &j) in idx.iter().enumerate() {
            rev[j] = i;
        }
        for i in 0..x.len() {
            while rev[i] != i {
                let j = rev[i];
                x.swap (j, i);
                rev.swap (j, i);
            }
        }
    }
    x
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=857b95c0bc7e3df83605ab01a594cd96)